# How to do not apply CSS on a specific TAG

Tags: html, css

I do not know if is possible in CSS, but I would like a general Role to don't apply to a specific element in my case `id=special`.
In my example all the DIV should be red but I want only `id=special` to have not applied this color.
I understand I can always overwrite the element with `id=special` but I'm interested to know if is possible have some sort of exclusion from the general Role.

Any idea in CSS 2 and CSS 3?

Example:

```
<div>this is red</div>
<div>this is red</div>
<div id="special">this one must be blus</div>
div>this is red</div>

// My General Role
div
{
  background-color:Red;
}
```

Comment: why not create style `#special { background-color: blue; }` - this would do what you want

Comment: thanks aleks for your suggestion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS2 Solution

```
div {
    color: red;
}

div#special {
    color: inherit;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zRxWW/1/

Answer (score 12):

CSS3 allows for the `:not()` selector:

```
div:not([id])
-or-
div:not(#special)
depending on what you want to exclude
```

[You can read all about the selectors in the w3c docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

As for CSS2, [there's a limited set of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching), and they don't account for negation.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, only complementing, in my case i used:

label:not(.radio){}

where radio is another style class. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

CSS3 solution:

```
div:not(#special)
```

Comment: cool! any other solution but in CSS 2? Thanks for your time on this!

Comment: Overriding... css2 does not have a solution for this I'm afraid. You can always use the solution of GerManson, but I would count that as overriding as well.

Comment: Specifying styles by ID (which override element styles) has existed since CSS1

Comment: @GibboK - What's preventing you from using this? IE's typical lack of support?

Comment: I have some wired problem with IE, but I meanly asked for learning propose thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use `div:not(#special)`, but if it's going to be blue anyways then you might as well just override the rule. The `:not()` selector is a CSS3 property and thus isn't supported by all browsers.

Comment: Awesome solution ! CSS3 power : ) Helped me a lot

Answer (score 3):

This is a great example of how CSS specificity works.  A general rule applying to all elements of a certain type (your `div` rule turning the background red) is superseded by the more specific rule applying to an ID. This concept has existed since CSS1, and is available in all browsers. Thus:

```
div {
  background-color:red;
}
#special {
 background-color: blue;  
}
```

... will leave all divs red. By applying the `special` id to a div, that one div will be blue instead.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9Hyas/

Check out these articles for more about CSS specificity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ and http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/